# What feedback evaluation tool would you recommend?

Tags: dashboard

We will soon be lauching a beta test with an app and would like to evaluate feedback that we
receive from the beta test group by email or phone.
Now the question for you:

Which tools are recommended for this? We would like to sort the answers according to features and other criteria and at the end get a dashboard that we can also present to our clients. Would be great if it were freeware too^^.

Comment: It can be enough to create a google form with a score for each subject

Answer (score 1):

[traggr](https://www.traggr.com) is a Feedback System allowing you to collect and analyze feedback from your users/customers and I think it fits well for your use-case. You can collect new feedback topics whenever you receive them via email or phone (or any other channel) and you can add more cases to existing topics. This allows you to track cases for feature requests and bug reports and later analyze their importance.
If you want, you can also upload your own customer list and link feedback cases to your (beta) users so you can keep the reference if you later would want to re-discuss a topic with one user.

Its analytics section could be what you desire with your dashboard request: it allows you to analyze the most important, recent and trending topics and filter them based on resolution state and tags you can freely assign to feedback. If you have been looking for something else regarding the dashboard, let me know.

There is a free plan so feel free to try it.
Disclaimer: I am part of the traggr team.